# Does mixed-sex education increase violence in schools?

Tags: education, gender, violence, school

[TSA-Alerie reports](http://www.tsa-algerie.com/20170309/debat-mefaits-de-mixite-a-lecole-suscite-polemique/) [French] that a poster on a conference at the National Library of Algeria has a controversial claim:

[image: Image of poster]

> La mixité sexuelle à l’école est la cause numéro un de la violence scolaire

which translates to:

> Mixed-sex schools are the number one cause of school violence.

The claim is from Smaïl Boulbina, an Algerian sexologist.

I'm very skeptical about that. Is mixed-sex education the largest factor - or even a factor at all - in school violence?

Comment: Seems to me that schools are the number one cause of school violence... we should just ban schools

Comment: Even if it does in Algeria (where it may be a cultural or religious thing that triggers such) that doesn't mean it does so everywhere. So you'd have to make the question far more specific.

Comment: @jwenting That could be included in the answers by specifying in what countries the research was done.

Comment: @JanDoggen sure, but the question infers that some poster in Algeria means that it's happening to pretty much the same degree everywhere.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this claim. You see, to get a *really* meaningful statistic, you'd need data from a country were *both* mixed-sex and separated-sex schools are *common*... or you'll look at "the common" type of school and the "special" kind of school, and will have a hard time ruling out that differences in violent events are due to the mixed / separated sex nature of those schools, and not due to whatever made the one kind "special" in a society where the other kind is the norm. -- So, my counterquestion would be, *is there a country where both school types coexist*?

Comment: I'm pretty sure at best we'd be able to show a correlation. Proving a causal relationship in this case is near impossible, because mixed and separated schools usually have a lot of other variables that change for them, the primary one being the cultural and social background of the parents.